# UITextField inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` that uses custom `UITableViewCell`. cell contains a `UITextField`. like in image below.
[image]

each TextField is configured in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. eg. `textContentType`, `keyboardType` etc.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReuseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! FormTableViewCell
    let inputItem = inputItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = inputItem.title
    cell.inputTextField.placeholder = inputItem.placeholder
    cell.inputTextField.textContentType = inputItem.contentType
    cell.inputTextField.keyboardType = inputItem.keyboardType
    cell.inputTextField.isSecureTextEntry = inputItem.isSecure

    return cell
}
```

However when editing last TextField(Re-Password) it shows email addresses as autofill suggestions although the `textContentType` is set to newPassword.

[image]

if tapped on one of the suggestions, the email(3rd textField) is populated with the email. not the textField that was being edited. also 4th textfield(password) becomes first responder.

[image]

weirdly, if I remove this line, the problem goes away

```
cell.inputTextField.isSecureTextEntry = inputItem.isSecure
```

InputItem class,

```
class InputItem:Mappable {
var title:String?
var placeholder:String?
var contentType:UITextContentType?
var keyboardType:UIKeyboardType?
var isSecure:Bool = false
}
```

Comment: if you have no use then you can turn off suggestions

Comment: use to UITextField inside Scroll-view, i hope work fine.

Comment: Could you please show us your inputItems array elements?

Comment: class InputItem {
 var title:String?
 var placeholder:String?
 var contentType:UITextContentType?
 var keyboardType:UIKeyboardType?
 var isSecure:Bool = false
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 // you can set autocorrectionType to turn on/off suggestions

 // UITextAutocorrectionType can be .no or .yes

 cell.inputTextField.autocorrectionType = inputItem.autocorrectionType // set .no to turn off suggestions
```

Comment: But it works for me there must be something else that is causing this issue